# Using global variables in functions with parameters in bash

Tags: bash, function, global-variables

I'm trying to catch a return value from a function in bash, that modify a global variable.
Works perfectly with funtions with no parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

tes=2
testfunction(){
        tes=3
        tes_str="string result"
        return 0
}
if output=testfunction; then
        echo "OK"
else
        echo "KO"
fi
echo $tes
echo $tes_str
```

But no with parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

tes=2
testfunction(){
        tes=3
        tes_str="string result"
        return 0
}
if output=$(testfunction "AA" "BB"); then
        echo "OK"
else
        echo "KO"
fi
echo $tes
echo $tes_str
```

Because for bash, parameters ("AA" or "BB") are a command, and I must put it in backets (but if use backets, can't modify global variables).
How can I do it? I'm stucked.
Regards

Comment: `Works perfectly with funtions with no parameters` No it doesn't, your code is invalid. `output=testfunction` only assigns the __text__ `testfunction` to `output`.

Comment: @Souf : Your first example does not execute `testfunction`. Your second example does. You can easily verify this by doing a `echo heloo >&2` inside testfunction.

Comment: Yes, It was a mistake, it's my fault, I wrote the simple code for this post, trying to explain the issue, catching the return value and calling a function with parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `output`? Just remove it and run the function.

```
if testfunction; then
```

Notes:

- `output=testfunction` is assigning the **text** `testfunction` to the variable `output`.
- `output=$(testfunction)` will not work, because `$(...)` runs everything inside a subshell.

Comment: Because without output assignment, I can't catch the return value. And first option yes, it was a mistake, it's my fault.
With `if testfunction; then` I can't catch the return value, and I can't pass the parameters.

Comment: I do not follow - no, I disagree with your statements. You can "catch" the return value and yes you can pass arguments. With command substitution you save _output_ of a command, you still may do that with temporary file. [repl bash example](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/GlitteringCoarseParallelcompiler#main.sh)

Comment: Yes, it works... I don't know why yesterday I can't do it... The only response is that I'm stupid... :(